# Grouping based on two variables in R

Tags: r

I want to find the mean, max value and mean, standard deviation for a data set.
The data set looks like this

```
Channel Region  Fresh   Milk    Grocery Frozen  Detergents_Paper
2        1     12669    9656    7561    214     2674
2        2      7057    9810    9568    1762    3293
2        3      6353    8808    7684    2405    3516
1        2     13265    1196    4221    6404    507
2        1     22615    5410    7198    3915    1777
2        3      9413    8259    5126    666     1795
```

From this i want to create a data set that has grouping with respect to Region and Channel with 
1. mean and max value for MILK against each group 
2. mean and standard deviation for Grocery against each group
i.e. the output should be like

```
Region  Channel Milk Mean   Milk max    Grocery Mean    Grocery SD
1         1             
1         2             
2         1             
2         2             
3         1             
3         2
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: For grouping functions, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega

Comment: Thanks a lot for help :)